# What kind of mushroom(?) is this?

Tags: botany, species-identification, parasitism

I found groups of these growing in the [Lassen National Forest](http://www.fs.usda.gov/lassen) (Susanville, CA, USA). It looks like some sort of mushroom. I have Googled extensively, but can't seem to find a match.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Found it. It's a Sarcodes or snow plant:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcodes

Comment: not a mushroom after all! How did you find it?

Comment: Wow this is allied to *Monotropa*. Thanks for link to wiki page